# Operational Risk Loss Distribution with Insurance

Tags: finance, risk-management, statistical-finance, insurance

[image: This is regarding operational losses of a financial institution with insurance. How is part (c) computed?]

**
Referring to part (c) First is 5000.  Am I supposed to replace the 8000 with 5000 while maintaining its probability?  For the second part, which includes the cost of insurance, do I add it to the loss amount for each group of risk?**

Comment: With insurance, 8000 losses are replaced by 5000 losses, but the company has a guaranteed loss of 500 (the insurance cost).

Comment: @Attack68 For losses with frequency 2, do I consider the insurance cost twice or just once?

Comment: No, 500 is a guaranteed loss, always payable. It is not only payable IF there is a loss

Comment: The insurance premium is only paid once per year.